# MongoDB: Does saving a document rewrite the whole document?

Tags: mongodb

I have the collection `domain` with documents that contain domain information. Part of that is the historical whois records, which may be zero or more and by far take up the majority of the space for the document.

If I load the entire document, change something small (like update a number field) and use the `save()` method will mongo flush the entire document to disk or only update the BSON that has changed? Ultimately my question is, should I bother complicating my code with `update()`'s to save on I/O or should I just use `save()`?

This isn't purely due to lazyness, the document (after it gets read in entirety) goes through a series of steps to modify/process the document and if any changes have been made the entire document is saved. But if the cost of saving the document is high then maybe I have to think about it a different way...

Answer (score 6):

You can update a single field in a document with [`$set`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set). This will modify the field on disk. However, [if the document grows beyond the size before the update, the document may have to be relocated on disk](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Padding+Factor).

Meanwhile, [here is what the documentation says about `save` versus `update`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29):

```
>// x is some JSON style object
>db.mycollection.save(x); // updates if exists; inserts if new
>
>// equivalent to:
>db.mycollection.update( { _id: x._id }, x, /*upsert*/ true );
```

**References**

- [Save versus update](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29)
- [The `$set` Modifier Operation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set)
- [Padding Factor](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Padding+Factor)

Comment: That is helpful, but it doesn't really answer my question. If I have a 10mb BSON document, I read it change one property and save it will it write the full 10mb again? Assuming the document does not have to be relocated.

Comment: The detail on *"is the whole thing written"* hinges on the fact that MongoDB uses memory-mapped files. If you update only a single property, then ideally only those bytes are flushed to the disk. However, if the BSON changes enough, then you *could* end up flushing the whole thing to disk.

Comment: @GatesVP: I thought that the whole page is marked dirty and has to be flushed.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you're right, it would be flushing a full page. Of course, you also get the problem where you have things on page boundaries. Honestly, these are really deep internals details and I'm pretty sure the answer here is buried deep in the source code and there are like 10 people in the world who really know how this works.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old, but it's very useful to know how it works to help you design your database structure. Here is the details about MongoDB's storage engine:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/faq/storage/

The document answers the question. Basically, if you update an integer field in MongoDB, it will mark the page(normally 4k) in memory where the integer resides in to be dirty and it will write memory page to disk on the next disk flush. So, if your document size is very big, the chance is that it will only write partial of your document into disk.

However, there are many other cases. If you are padding more data to your document, there is chances that MongoDB needs to move the entire document to a new location for the document to grow. In that case, the entire document will be written to disk.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I skim docs over and over again, but I cannot find this info.  I cannot find anything that explicitly shows how memory pages are marked dirty and written into the disk.  Would you help me?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on a client library you are using. For example, Mongoid (ODM in ruby) is smart enough to only send fields that were changed (using `$set` command). It is sometimes too smart and doesn't catch changes that I made to nested hashes. But I've never seen it send unchanged fields.

Other libraries/drivers may behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently going through the "Introduction to MongoDB" University course and on the "MongoDB Data Modeling Intro" module it states that "Embedding data will make the document larger and impact write performance. As more data is added to each document, the entire document is rewritten into MongoDB data storage". I hope this helps!